# swagger: requestBody not allowed

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm trying to define a post endpoint using swagger, but it isn't allowing the `requestBody` parameter:

```
  /names/{roster}:
    get:
      #...
    post:
      x-swagger-router-controller: names
      description: Adds or removes name(s)
      operationId: manageNames
      parameters:
      - name: roster
        in: path
        description: the roster to use
        type: string
        required: true
      requestBody:
        content:
          'application/json':
            schema:
              $ref: '#/definitions/ManageNamesRequest'
```

when I run `npm start`, I get this:

```
API Errors:

  #/paths/~1names~1{roster}/post: Additional properties not allowed: requestBody

1 error and 0 warnings
```

What's wrong with my spec?

Comment: `requestBody` is OpenAPI 3.0 syntax. Does your tool support OpenAPI 3.0?

Comment: I'm using swagger version 2.0. I'm not sure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably mixing OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 and OpenAPI 3.0 syntax. Your spec seems to be 2.0, but the `requestBody` keyword is a 3.0 feature. In 2.0, the request body is defined as a body parameter:

```yaml
paths:
  /names/{roster}:
    post:
      produces:
        - application/json
      ...
      parameters:
      - ...
      - in: body
        name: body
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/ManageNamesRequest'
```

More info: [Describing Request Body](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/)